# pyautogui._pyautogui_osx' has no attribute '_size'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm really new as developper and I tried to run a Autospam bot as a trial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBxRGcDmfWA

After pip3 install pyautogui, I did the following code :

```
import time
import pyautogui

time.sleep(5)
f = open("requirements", 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Problem is I get this following issue :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rubicon/objc/ctypes_patch.py:21: UserWarning: rubicon.objc.ctypes_patch has only been tested with Python 3.4 through 3.8. You are using Python 3.9.0. Most likely things will work properly, but you may experience crashes if Python's internals have changed significantly.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidbonavia/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/testtchatbot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 2144, in <module>
    _right, _bottom = size()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 769, in size
    return Size(*platformModule._size())
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui._pyautogui_osx' has no attribute '_size'
```

I tried to check what is Rubicon and how to solve this problem, but I have really no idea. Someone can help me on this please ?

Cheers all

Comment: Read the warning? `rubicon.objc.ctypes_patch has only been tested with Python 3.4 through 3.8. You are using Python 3.9.0`... `you may experience crashes`

Comment: Yes I read, there is any solution to avoid this ?

Comment: Well, did you try installing/using a lower version of Python?

Comment: Is there any way to launch with lower version Python or should I install it again ? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Python3.9 can only run Python3.9... You can install different versions of python using a tool called pyenv, though